# How can I use my Canon Pixma network scanner?

Tags: debian, networking, scanner, sane, pureos

I have successfully configured a Canon Pixma MX494 as a network printer from my laptop (PureOS/Debian) using CUPS. It appears under "Printers" and I can print a test page over the network.

I can successfully scan over the network from my Android device using the Canon app.

I am now trying to configure the same device as a *network* scanner from my laptop.

Following https://wiki.debian.org/SaneOverNetwork#Client_Configuration I have:

- Installed `libsane` and `sane-utils` (already installed)
- Uncomment the net backend entry in `/etc/sane.d/dll.conf` (already uncommented)
- Added the IP address of the scanner to `/etc/sane.d/net.conf` (Although, from the link "Note that the net backend is not for accessing arbitrary scanners over a network.")
- I can ping the scanner at its IP address from my laptop

But `scanimage -L` does not detect the scanner. (It seemed to detect it once, but `simple-scan` then failed, and it has not detected it again since then.)

Comment: I had the same behavior (simple-scan error and lockout from the scanner), I had to restart my printer/scanner to be able to reconnect. Maybe it's worth a trial.

Answer (score 1):

There is a tool ScanGear MP Ver. 3.10 for Linux available on the Canon website (source, RPM and Debian package):

- [ScanGear MP Ver. 3.10 for Linux / IJ Printer Driver Ver. 5.10 for Linux](https://www.canon-europe.com/support/consumer_products/products/fax__multifunctionals/inkjet/pixma_mx_series/pixma_mx494.html?type=drivers&language=en&os=linux%20(64-bit))

And there are two How To's on the Debian User Forums site for the Pixma MX490 series.

- [How to: Scanner Install Canon PIXMA MX490 series](http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?f=16&t=132608#p640822)
- [Solved, CUPS printer driver Canon PIXMA MX490 series](http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?f=17&t=132606)

---

The PIXMA MX490 series is listed as "Untested" on the sane project site, so it's possible that it doesn't work with sane at all.

[SANE: Supported Devices](http://www.sane-project.org/lists/sane-mfgs-cvs.html)

> PIXMA MX490 Series    USB WiFi    0x04a9/0x1787   Untested    Testers needed!

[sane-pixma.5](http://www.sane-project.org/man/sane-pixma.5.html)

> The  following  models  may use the same Pixma protocol as those
>   listed above, but have not yet been  reported  to  work  (or  not). 
>   They  are declared  in  the  backend  so  that they get recognized and
>   activated. Feedback in the sane-devel mailing list welcome.
>
> PIXMA E400, E460, E470, E480, E500, E510, E560, E600, E610
>         PIXMA MG3000, MG4100, MG6500, MG6600, MG6800, MG6900, MG8100
>         PIXMA MP375R, MP493, MP495, MP740
>         PIXMA MX320, MX390, MX430, MX450, **MX490**, MX710